# Infix to postfix conversion in MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

This is my assignment to do simple calculation of the content from an input file by using MASM. The book we use is "Assembly language for x86 processor".

Now I am trying to do infix to postfix conversion. The input I tried to convert is : `12/3+4`, but it just stopped and showed that .exe has stopped working, and I found out that it stops at the `INVOKE CheckAddSub` in main function.

Could you help me see what has gone wrong in that proc? I have tried to use stack to push/pop but then I changed to this because since I am calling function, I think it would be easier to do this without using stack. Thank you so so much for your time to look at my code.

```
INCLUDE C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE C:\Irvine\macros.inc
CheckAddSub PROTO, seStr1:PTR BYTE, outStr1:PTR BYTE, pCo:DWORD, pDo:DWORD, 
outCo1:DWORD
CheckMulDiv PROTO, seStr2:PTR BYTE, outStr2:PTR BYTE, theCo:DWORD, 
theDo:DWORD, outCo2:DWORD

.data
inputStr BYTE 20 dup(?)    ;input array
outputStr BYTE 20 dup(?)   ;postfix array
sizeSt DWORD 20
secStr BYTE 10 dup(?)    ;to store the operator
count DWORD 0
dStr BYTE 0
outCount DWORD 0

.code
main PROC
    mWrite "Input: "
    mov edx, OFFSET inputStr 
    mov ecx, SIZEOF inputStr - 1
    call ReadString
    mov esi, OFFSET inputStr     ;now the input str has elements
    mov edi, OFFSET outputStr    ;for storing the postfix 
    mov ecx, sizeSt              ;to loop
    mov edx, OFFSET secStr       ;to store operator

L1:
    mov ebx, [esi]
    .if bl=='+'|| bl=='-' 
        inc count             

    .if count > 1           ;when count is 2 mean there is already element in 
                             the secStr array so i can do the checking
        INVOKE CheckAddSub, ADDR secStr, ADDR outputStr, count, dStr,outCount
        inc dStr        ;dStr is to store the index number of the secStr 
                         array, after the zero index predencency is checked, 
                        ;increment dStr to indicate the index number this 
                         current operator in secStr array

    .endif

    mov [edx],ebx     ;put the operator into secStr
    add edx,1

    .elseif bl=='*'|| bl =='/'
        inc count

    .if count > 1
        INVOKE CheckMulDiv, ADDR secStr, ADDR outputStr , count, dStr, outCount
        inc dStr
    .endif

    mov [edx],ebx   
    add edx,1

    .else                  ;when it is operand(number), put into output array
       mov [edi], ebx
       inc outCount
    .endif

    inc edi
    inc esi
    dec ecx  
    cmp ecx,0
    jne L1    

    mov edx, OFFSET outputStr
    mWrite "the postfix string is: "
    call WriteString

   INVOKE ExitProcess,0

 main ENDP
 ;-----------------------------------------------------------
 CheckAddSub PROC USES edx edi eax ecx ebx,
 seStr1:PTR BYTE,      ;secStr
 outStr1:PTR BYTE,     ;outputStr
 pCo:DWORD, 
 pDo:DWORD,
 outCo1:DWORD
;------------------------------------------------------------

    mov edx, seStr1      
    mov edi, outStr1

LW:
    mov ebx, [edx+pDo]            ;edx+pDo is the last element in the array, 
                                     like stack the top element
    .if bl=='+'|| bl=='-'|| bl=='*' || bl=='/'
         mov [edi+outCo1],ebx      ;if one of these operator exists in the 
                                    secStr array, then put this operator into 
                                    the outputStr array 
         mov [edx+pDo], 0          ;put null in this current index,indicating 
                                    this element is already pop out from the 
                                    secStr array    
         inc outCo1 
    .endif

    .if pDo!=0
         sub pDo,1
    .endif

    dec pCo         
    cmp pCo,1
    jne LW
    je L5

L5: ret 

CheckAddSub ENDP

;------------------------------------------------------
CheckMulDiv PROC USES edx edi eax ecx ebx,
  seStr2:PTR BYTE, 
  outStr2:PTR BYTE, 
  theCo:DWORD, 
  theDo:DWORD,
  outCo2:DWORD
;-------------------------------------------------------

   mov edx, seStr2
   mov edi, outStr2

LR:
   mov ebx,[edx+theDo]
   .if bl=='*'|| bl=='/'
      mov [edi+outCo2],ebx
      mov [edx+theDo],0
      inc outCo2
   .endif

   .if theDo!=0
     sub theDo,1
   .endif

   dec theCo
   cmp theCo, 1
   jne LR
   je L6

L6: ret

CheckMulDiv ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I tried to put Hello at the beginning of the post but i dont know why it just disappear after i saved edits. Just dont want to sound rude, so I will say Hi here.

Comment: Greetings (e.g., "Hello") and signatures (e.g., "Thanks" and your user name) are automatically stripped out of posts because they are considered "noise". Don't worry, it isn't considered rude when you leave these out. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the information~

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> call ReadString
> mov esi, OFFSET inputStr     ;now the input str has elements
> mov edi, OFFSET outputStr    ;for storing the postfix 
> mov ecx, sizeSt              ;to loop
> ```

You're using a fixed number of iterations. In this case, 20, because *sizeSt* was defined that way.

What you want is to iterate over the bytes that you actually received. You got this count in `EAX` from *ReadString*, so use it:

```
call ReadString
mov esi, OFFSET inputStr     ;now the input str has elements
mov edi, OFFSET outputStr    ;for storing the postfix 
mov ecx, eax                 ;to loop
```

---

> ```
> mov ebx, [esi]
> ...
> mov [edx], ebx
> ...
> mov [edi], ebx
> ```

Since you're processing **bytes**, you must use the byte-sized `BL` register instead of the DWORD-sized `EBX` register!

---

> ```
> dStr BYTE 0
> ```

Considering the `PROTO`/`INVOKE`, you need to change this into:

```
dStr DWORD 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have did what you said, changing all the ebx to bl, which was what I have did before but it gives error messages "invalid instruction operand" at both proc... mov bl,[edx+pDo] at the CheckAddSub PROC, i wonder why because that array is byte array.. both operands are the same type

Comment: Try the following `mov ecx, pDo` followed by `mov bl, [edx + ecx]`

Comment: You say these arrays are byte arrays, but in an instruction like `mov bl,[edx+pDo]` there's really nothing that points at this *byte-ness*. `EDX` is just another register.

Comment: So the compiler does not know what type of element being moved from that array? I thought we need to match the data type of the register with the element from the array. Btw now no errors but the result is wrong...Thanks for your help again!

Comment: As long as you use symbolic names like *seStr1*, the compiler will be able to tell anything about the size of the items involved. Once you move this name in a register like with `mov edx, seStr1`, subsequent use of [edx] no longer offers this recognition.

Comment: @chloe.t also it's basically only MASM from x86 assemblers trying to do somewhat bigger "type" effort during compilation (and you can easily override it like `mov bl, byte ptr [SomeDwordArray]`, most of the assemblers don't care and it's up to the programmer to allocate correct amount of memory and use correctly sized registers and algorithm/instructions to get desired result. The less you expect from assemblers, the better it will go for you. While this may look as a burden, it also gives you freedom to do "any thing", if the CPU itself is capable of it, you can write it in assembly.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, you can upvote and accept it. The upvote I just gave on your question gives you this privilege.